# Cannot find property setter for "Chars"

Tags: char, delphi-prism, oxygene

I am trying to do the following expression, but I keep running into this exception, "Cannot find property setter for 'chars'."

Here is the expression:

```
xstr, str : string;
for i := 1 to length(str) do
begin
  if ((i mod 2)<>0) then
  begin
    xstr[i] := char(Ord(str[i]) xor $AA);  <<<<------ Exception Raised
  end
  else
  begin
    xstr[i] := char(Ord(str[i]) xor $55);  <<<<------ Exception Raised
  end;
end;
```

The value of "str" is passed into the encryption method.

This is part of an encryption method. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`System.String` is an immutable class, meaning you cannot modify instances of it. .NET requires modifying string operations to create new instances of a string. For your purpose, it’s probably easiest and most efficient to create a `char` array of the modified characters and then construct a string from that.

In general, the [`System.Text.StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) class offers a mutable string instance.

In fact, even if it weren’t for the immutability of strings, your code would fail because you didn’t *allocate* a string, so assignment to `xstr[i]` would  yield in a buffer overflow exception. You need to do that when using an array of `char`.

Comment: how about unsafe solution using pointers? is it possible in delphi?

Comment: @Kuba Maybe. But what advantage would it have? *Maybe* performance. But probably not even that.

Comment: @KubaWyrostek it's not safe and almost never recommended.

Comment: I was just curious as I know how to do it in C#.

Comment: Konrad, your answer is just what I needed. I was able to modify my code and have it working. Thanks.